# How this code can be used as a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I wanted the below code in a Wordpress shortcode so it can be used like [testimonials], I have tried a lot of times and failed miserably, ideas would be GREATLY appreciated:

```
<div class="row cols3 testimonials">
<?php $postnum=1; query_posts('post_type=testimonial&showposts=3'); if (have_posts()) $post = $posts[0]; $c=0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<article class="col<?php if($postnum ==1){echo" first";}elseif($postnum==3){echo" last";}?>">
<p><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p>
<div class="arrow"><div class="tri"></div></div>
<div class="name"><strong><?php global $post;$text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_testominal_author', true );echo $text;?></strong> - <?php global $post;$text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_testominal_company', true );echo $text;?></div>
</article>
<?php $postnum++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div><!-- /Testimonials -->
```

****UPDATE****

The below code works, I really have no idea how though, I'm not exactly confident to use it because I don't understand how it works. Any help would be amazing:

```
<?php
function testimonials_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
$the_query = new WP_Query();
$the_query->query($atts);
if ($the_query->have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) :  
$the_query->the_post(); ob_start(); ?>

<div class="row cols3 testimonials">
<?php $postnum=1; query_posts('post_type=testimonial&showposts=3'); if (have_posts()) $post = $posts[0]; $c=0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<article class="col<?php if($postnum ==1){echo" first";}elseif($postnum==3){echo" last";}?>">
<p><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p>
<div class="arrow"><div class="tri"></div></div>
<div class="name"><strong><?php global $post;$text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_testominal_author', true );echo $text;?></strong> - <?php global $post;$text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_testominal_company', true );echo $text;?></div>
</article>
<?php $postnum++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div><!-- /Testimonials -->

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); 
$content = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();
return $content;
}

add_shortcode('testimonials', 'testimonials_shortcode');
?>
```

Comment: In its current form, this question should probably be migrated to WP.se.

Comment: The hardest part to understand is the `ob_start`, ect. These functions make PHP capture the code where it would normally be outputted to screen and collects it into a object to be `returned` later. The rest is simply WordPress loops, coded the RIGHT way and not using `query_posts`, which is bad. See the Codex under WP_Query for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for (minus the post counting). Paste this into you `functions.php` and use as `[testimonials]` in the Post Editor, or in directly in templates with `<?php echo do_shortcode("[testimonials]");`

```
function testimonials_function(){ 

  ob_start();
  ?>
  <div class="row cols3 testimonials">
  <?php 

  $custom_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=testimonial&posts_per_page=3' );

  if($custom_query->have_posts()) :

     while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();
     ?>
            <article>
              <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
              <div class="arrow"><div class="tri"></div></div>
              <div class="name"><strong><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_id(),'_cmb_testominal_author', true ); ?></strong> - <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_id(),'_cmb_testominal_company', true ); ?></div>
           </article>   
    <?php       
    endwhile;

  endif;

  // Reset Post Data
  wp_reset_postdata();

  $content =  ob_get_contents();
  ob_clean();

  return $content;

}

add_shortcode('testimonials','testimonials_function');
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks you so much! That code makes a lot more sense than the old one did, really appreciate the help, works perfectly! Cheers.

Comment: Brilliant! If it's the winning solution, vote for my answer. Thanks